# Weakly Diagonally Dominant with Positive Diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, diagonalization

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (not necessarily symmetric) is weakly diagonally dominant with positive diagonals. Is it true that all eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative (in the case of complex eigenvalues, have non-negative real parts)? Note that this holds true for strictly diagonally dominant matrices: if the matrix is symmetric with non-negative diagonal entries, the matrix is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Correct! But, in the case of complex eigenvalues, we need the real part of the eigenvalues to be non-negative.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)?

Comment: Yes! I am familiar with that.

Comment: I guess I got your point. In this case, all circles in the Gershgorin circle theorem  will be on the right-half plane will possible intersection with the imaginary axis!